# Understanding loops in-conjunction with if/elif/else statements (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Evening all,

I'm new to programming and I am attempting to understanding while loops that are used with if/elif/else statements.

**My Thought Process**

The function that I have created is a part of the game Tic Tac Toe (or Noughts and Crosses). The idea behind the function is to prompt Player 1 for their symbol choice (O or X).

My logic behind the function is such that, the player will continue to be prompted (the loop) for a valid choice. Once the player has made a valid choice, the loop should end and print the player's choice.

**My Question**

What I don't understand is that the function only works if I include *break* at the end of both the IF and ELIF blocks of code. Why won't the loop *break* upon the user entering a valid choice?

Please see the code, written in Python, below.

Regards,

```
def player_input():
    player1_input = str
    player1_symbol = str
       
    while player1_symbol != "X" or "O": #loop until user supplies an valid (X or O) input
        player1_input = str(input("\nPlayer 1, would you like to be X or O?:  ")) #prompt user for their choice
        player1_symbol = player1_input #link player1_input to player1_symbol
    
        if player1_symbol == "X": #follow this block if Player 1 selected X
            print("\nPlayer 1: You are now X") #states that Player 1 is X
            print("Player 2: You are now O") #states that Player 2 is now O as a result of Player 1's choice
            print("IF Statement Executed") #lets me know that this block was executed
            break #WHY DO I NEED THIS TO BREAK THE LOOP IF A VALID SELECTION WAS MADE?
            
        elif player1_symbol == "O": #follow this block if Player 1 selected O
            print("\nPlayer 1: You are now O") #states that Player 1 is O
            print("Player 2: You are now X") #states that Player 2 is now O as a result of Player 1's choice
            print("ELIF Statement Executed") #lets me know that this block was executed
            break #AGAIN, WHY DO I NEED THIS TO BREAK THE LOOP IF A VALID SELECTION WAS MADE
            
        else:
            print("\nInvalid choice. Please choose X or O.") #lets Player 1 know that he needs to make a valid (X or O) input
            print("ELSE Statement Executed") #lets me know that this block was executed
```

Comment: "X" or "O" is not the preferred nomenclature, you may find `while player1_symbol != "X" and player1_symbol !="O"` to work better for you. Or more succinctly `while player1_symbol not in ["X","O"]`

Comment: `while player1_symbol != "X" or "O":` is almost certainly not what you meant

Comment: Thanks @Chris, the ' while player1_symbol not in ["X","O"] ' is quite handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment gives the appropriate fix. To understand why this is happening, note that the `or` operator combines two separate logic statements. In your case, these two logic statements are `player1_symbol != "X"` as well as `"O"`. Because the latter statement is nonzero, python always evaluates it as `True` so that the entire statement `player1_symbol != "X" or "O"` is always true, no matter the value of `player1_symbol`.

Edit: To be clear what I mean by "the latter statement is nonzero", I mean the ASCII value for the character "O" is nonzero, so python evaluates it as true.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the condition is not well formulated:

Comment: So it should be fixed like this: player1_symbol != "X" or player1_symbol != "O"